# Is it possible to avoid locking overhead when sharing dicts between threads in Python?

Tags: python, multithreading, immutability

I have a multi-threaded application in Python where threads are reading very large (so I cannot copy them to thread-local storage) dicts (read from disk and never modified). Then they process huge amounts of data using the dicts as read-only data:

```
# single threaded
d1,d2,d3 = read_dictionaries()
while line in stdin:
    stdout.write(compute(line,d1,d2,d3)+line)
```

I am trying to speed this up by using threads, which would then each read its own input and write its own output, but since the dicts are huge, I want the threads to share the storage.

IIUC, every time a thread reads from the dict, it has to lock it, and that imposes a performance cost on the application. This data locking is not necessary because the dicts are read-only.

Does CPython actually lock the data individually or does it just use the [GIL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_interpreter_lock)?

If, indeed, there is per-dict locking, is there a way to avoid it?

Comment: please post an example code of what you are doing now

Comment: What specifically are you referring to when you say "locking overhead"? I suspect the Global Interpreter Lock could well be the biggest issue, but then it's not clear from the question how the overhead is specific to dicts in particular.

Comment: you can use multiprocessing to get around the gil ... but somehow i dont think thats quite what you want ... why not load the dicts into logparse or even just redis or something?

Comment: If you use Jython or IronPython (I think neither have Python 3 support), they don't have the GIL.  I don't think there's any way to do this with CPython (from Python.org), but you might be able to [get around it using Cython's "with nogil"](http://docs.cython.org/src/userguide/external_C_code.html#acquiring-and-releasing-the-gil).  I'm not sure about that, though, for your use case.

Comment: as far as im concerned this is a problem best solved with a logparse server

Comment: @NPE: I thought that there is a per-datum lock. Is there? (please see edit)

Comment: @JoranBeasley: could you please clarify how would a logparse server help here?

Comment: @sds, can you clarify character of your data and your processing algorithm? Maybe you can write a example using pseudocode?

Comment: @Jimilian: done - I hope this clarifies my intent

Comment: @sds, I tried to guess your algorithm and added some possible solutions to my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Multithreading processing in python is useless. It's better to use multiprocessing module. Because multithreading can give positive effort only in lower number of cases.

> Python implementation detail: In CPython, due to the Global
>   Interpreter Lock, only one thread can execute Python code at once
>   (even though certain performance-oriented libraries might overcome
>   this limitation). If you want your application to make better use of
>   the computational resources of multi-core machines, you are advised to
>   use multiprocessing. However, threading is still an appropriate model
>   if you want to run multiple I/O-bound tasks simultaneously.
>   [Official documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html).

Without any code examples from your side I can only recommend to split your big dictionary on several parts and process every part using [Pool.map](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#module-multiprocessing.pool). And merge results in main process.

Unfortunately, it's impossible to share a lot of memory between different python processes effective (we are not talking about shared memory pattern based on [mmap](https://docs.python.org/2/library/mmap.html)). But you can read different parts of your dictionary in different processes. Or just read entire dictionary in main process and give a small chunks to child processes.

Also, I should warn you that you should be very carefully with multiprocessing algorithms. Because every extra megabytes will be multiplied on number of process.

So, based on your pseudocode example I can assume two possible algorithm based on `compute` function:

```
# "Stateless"
for line in stdin:
    res = compute_1(line) + compute_2(line) + compute_3(line)
    print res, line

# "Shared" state
for line in stdin:
    res = compute_1(line)
    res = compute_2(line, res)
    res = compute_3(line, res)
    print res, line
```

In first case, you can create a several workers, read each dictionary in separate worker based on [Process class](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#process-and-exceptions) (it's good idea to decrease memory usage for each process), and compute it like a production line.

In second case, you have a shared state. For each next worker you need a result of previous one. It's worst case for multithreading/multiprocessing programming. But you can write algorithm there several workers are using same Queue and pushing result to it without waiting finish of all cycle. And you just share a [Queue](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#pipes-and-queues) instance between your processes.

Comment: how would I share the memory used by dicts between subprocesses?

Comment: @sds, I added some details about memory sharing to my answer.