# Run a function in parallel with different arguments - python

Tags: python, multithreading, parallel-processing

I have a function `slow_function` which takes about 200 seconds to process a `job_title`, it reads and writes to / from a global variable.

There is no improvement in performance using this code. Am I missing something, this however returns the same results.

Code running five job categories in parallel:

```
    from threading import Thread
    threads = []

    start = time.time()
    for job_title in self.job_titles:
        t = Thread(target=self.slow_function, args=(job_title,))
        threads.append(t)
    # Start all threads
    for x in threads:
        x.start()

     # Wait for all of them to finish
    for x in threads:
        x.join()
    end = time.time()
    print "New time taken for all jobs:", end - start
```

Comment: Please, read this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32657840/is-it-possible-to-avoid-locking-overhead-when-sharing-dicts-between-threads-in-p/32659672#32659672. I'm not sure is your question duplicated or not, but it could help you.

Comment: Thanks. Your solution worked for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should extract slow_function from class method, because it's impossible to share local context between processes. And after that you can use this code:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

start = time.time()

pool = Pool()

results = pool.map(slow_function, self.job_titles)

for r in results:
   # update your `global` variables here

end = time.time()
print "New time taken for all jobs:", end - start
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the multiprocessing (https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html) module, since the threading module is limited by the GIL (https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-global-interpreter-lock).

But you can not use global variables for exchanging data between spawned processes!!! ... see https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#exchanging-objects-between-processes